# ocl mean shift segmentation in opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have done mean shift segmentation on an image in opencv using the following code

```
ocl::meanShiftSegmentation(cv::ocl::oclMat(mImagePar),mTarget,5,15,20);
```

I have got the mean-shift-segmented image as an output. But I don't know how to access the segmented clusters. If there are 5 colored segmented clusters, I want to access each one of them and their locations.

I know my question is pretty vague. But I don't get any clue as on how I can get the clusters. There is not enough documentation on accessing them. On googling, I have only got some mean-shift implementation in codes, which is too hard and long to understand.

You have any idea on getting the segmented regions ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other versions, but meanshift in ocl (Ver. 2.4.9) doesn't give you access to clusters, just gives you the final segmented image. you can separate clusters by their colour, just trace pixels in final image and consider same colour pixels as a cluster.